# Angular 6 form builder array error

Tags: angular

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'partners -> 0 -> partner'

Can't seem to get this form builder array to compile. I practically worked off of the example provided [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ayqnbvbkmpy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-detail%2Fhero-detail.component.ts). Been looking at this for way too long, any help appreciated. I feel/hope it's something small I've over looked.

```js
constructor() {
  this.createForm();
}

createForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    partners: this.fb.array([])
  });
}

get partners(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('partners') as FormArray;
}


addPartner() {
  this.partners.push(this.fb.group(new Partner()));
}

 export class Partner {
  partner: '';
  segment: '';
  market: '';
  supervisor: '';
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formArrayName="partners" *ngIf="partners.length">
        <div
            *ngFor="let partner of form.controls.partners.controls; let i=index"
            [formGroupName]="i">
        </div>
        <button type="button" (click)="addPartner()">&#43; Add Partner</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The code you posted never tries to access the path mentioned in the error. And we have no idea of what new Partner() does.

Comment: @JBNizet added partner class, updated access path in the view(is that what you meant?), and included form tag in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare this

```
form: FormGroup;
```

Comment: Wish it was that easy, I’ve kept a lot of the boiler plate out of the question to keep it as concise as possible. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is from this line:

```
<div formArrayName="partners" *ngIf="partners.length">
```

I suggest then to replace with:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="partners.length">
   <div formArrayName="partners" >
      ...
   </div>
<ng-container>
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but unfortunately did not solve the issue. For some reason when `new Partner()` is called its empty. I'm guessing it has to do with the way I generate the new Partner obj. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I want to say it might've been a combination of things which got this working. Hopefully it might help someone else. Thanks to @JBNizet for pointing me in the right direction.

So first, I had my `*ngFor` access path incorrect. If you noticed my form builder group has a path to partners like this:

right: `form.controls.partners.controls`
wrong:(which is what I had) `partners.controls`

Secondly, my exported partner class always returns an empty object when I called it like so `new Partner()`:

```js
// This file was in a models file, imported into class.
// For some reason doesn't work...
export class Partner {
  partner: '';
  segment: '';
  market: '';
  supervisor: '';
}

// Being used here: 
addPartner() {
  this.partners.push(this.fb.group(new Partner()));
}
```

I ended having to do this to get the correct `formGroup` populated with expected `new Partner()` object.

```js
// This method was inside same class.
// This works just fine.
newPartner() {
  return {
    partner: ['', Validators.required],
    segment: ['', Validators.required],
    market: ['', Validators.required],
    supervisor: ['', Validators.required]
  };
}

// Being used here: 
addPartner() {
  this.partners.push(this.fb.group(this.newPartner()));
}
```